# C# how to check if adjacent values are greater or smaller in an array and allocate points based on values?

Tags: c#, arrays

I am trying to figure out how to assign points based on adjacent number values in an array. By default, each number is worth one point, and it increases in value if the adjacent numbers are lower than the current number.

For values at the start and the end of the array, the adjacent values are the end and start, so for `numbers[0]` adjacent values are `numbers[5] && numbers[1]` and for `numbers[5]` the values would be `numbers[4] && numbers[0]`. Consider it going in a circle.

As an example of numbers let's say we have `int[] numbers = new int[] { 5, 6, 4, 2, 5, 6 };` after point allocation the output should be something like `1 3 2 1 2 3`.

The issue I'm facing is that I don't know how to write the code in such a way that I don't get an error. And I would like to avoid using a lot of if nested functions. Managed to get it working like that but it looks horrible, so scrapped that and figured there must be a better way of doing this but I seem to be stuck...

```
        static int[] AssignPoints (int[] numbers) {
            int[] points = new int[numbers.Length];
            for (int i = 0; i < numbers.Length; i++) {
                points[i]++; //allocating initial point
                ???

            }
            
            return points;
        }
```

Comment: so minimum value is always 1 and maximum value always 3?

Comment: Yes, the minimum will always be 1 if the adjacent numbers are bigger than the current number and maximum be 3 if adjacent are smaller than the current number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A very explicit example:

```
static int[] AssignPoints (int[] numbers) {
    int[] points = new int[numbers.Length];
    for (int i = 0; i < numbers.Length; i++) {
        var leftIndex = i == 0 ? numbers.Length - 1 : i - 1;
        var rightIndex = i == numbers.Length - 1 ? 0 : i + 1;

        points[i] = 1
            + (numbers[i] > numbers[leftIndex] ? 1 : 0)
            + (numbers[i] > numbers[rightIndex] ? 1 : 0);
    }
    return points;
}
```

Comment: Thanks!! This works as expected, only modification I did was set the ```points[i] = 0``` instead of ```1```. If it was set to ```1```. It would increase values that had to be 1 to 2.

Comment: @David alright, if it works for you :) But you did say "By default, each number is worth one point".

Comment: True, I did say that but also gave some examples of what should be saved so that there is no confusion. But thanks anyway!!!

Answer (score 2):

```
    static int[] AssignPoints (int[] numbers) {
       int[] points = new int[numbers.Length];
       for (int i = 0; i < numbers.Length; i++) 
       {
         int prevIndex = (i-1 < 0 ? numbers.Length -1 : i-1);
         int nextIndex = (i+1 >= numbers.Length ? 0 : i + 1);

         if (numbers[i] > numbers[prevIndex])
            points[i]++;

         if (numbers[i] > numbers[nextIndex])
            points[i]++;
       }
       return points;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer as well, this also works but needed just a bit of tweaking, instead po points in the ifs it needed to be changed to numbers and I added the initial points[i]++ at the start of the loop.

Answer (score 0):

```
        static List<int> AssignPoints(List<int> numbers)
        {

            List<int> points =new List<int>(numbers.Capacity);
            int i = 0, point;

            foreach (int item in numbers)
            {
                point = 1;

                if(i != 0)
                    if (numbers[i - 1] < numbers[i]) point++;
                if(i != numbers.Capacity -1)
                    if (numbers[i + 1] < numbers[i]) point++;

                i++;
                points.Add(point);
            }
            
            return points;
        }
```